# What are the similarity and difference between quantum fidelity estimation and parameter estimation problem?

Tags: fidelity, quantum-metrology

Quantum fidelity [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states) estimation is to estimate the similarity between two quantum states or process. Could quantum fidelity be viewd as a parameter? And what are the similarity and difference between quantum fidelity estimation and parameter estimation problem?

---

***[Cross-posted on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/771864/58382)***

Comment: without further context this is a bit vague. You can try to estimate the fidelity between two states used as input and think of it as a parameter to estimate, sure. So "fidelity estimation" will in this sense be an instance of "parameter estimation"

Comment: Yeah, that's resonable. But, in this sense, what is the quantum fisher information of this parameter, i.e., fidelity?